# liquibase configuration xml change, that allow Change Set to be export in sql query files not to run on DB?

Tags: sql, liquibase

How to generate or configure the liquibase to generate and save the database changes in the sql rather then, liquibase run directly agnist the database.

I am looking for liquibase configuration that allow all the change-set query to export to SQL file. Then we can manually run those quer disabling auto commit to verify the changes.

I am aware, that liquibase support execute custom script (SQL) during the change Set  execution. with following changes in

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sqlFile-example">
    <sqlFile dbms="h2, oracle"
            encoding="utf8"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            path="my/path/file.sql"....
```

Ss I am looking for reverse of [Change: ‘sqlFile’](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) exporting generate SQL statement to file or console.

If any anyone knows please let me know?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you provide more details? Are you searching for something like this https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/updateSQL-mojo.html ?

Comment: How to generate or configure the liquibase to generate and save the database changes in the sql rather then, liquibase run directly agnist the database.

Comment: migrationSqlOutputFile:

The file to output the Migration SQL script to, if it exists it will be overwritten.
Type: java.io.File
Required: No
Expression: ${liquibase.migrationSqlOutputFile}
Default: ${project.build.directory}/liquibase/migrate.sql

Seems it will work or this could solve my problem but I am not abel to figure it out.

Comment: edit your question and post details. without them nobody will help you.